# Keyboard shortcut for C# Console Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shortcut

I know the shortcut for `Console.WriteLine()` is type **cw** and <kbd>tab</kbd> twice. Does anyone know what's the short cut for `Console.ReadLine()` ?

Comment: I doubt there is one, but if you have ReSharper installed you can define your own templates.

Comment: Just create your own snippet if it doesn't exist

Comment: ctrl k ctrl x and you can view all the snippets

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Save the following as a `.snippet` and import it (used the cw snippet as a template)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>cr</Title>
            <Shortcut>cr</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for Console.ReadLine</Description>
            <Author>Whoever you want it to be</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>SystemConsole</ID>
                    <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Console)</Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$SystemConsole$.ReadLine();]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Once imported, you can hit **cr** and <kbd>tab</kbd> twice to get `Console.Readline();`

Comment: Make sure to save it in the following directory (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\), in my case it worked!

Answer (score 13):

There is no shortcut(code snippet) for `Console.ReadLine()`. However you can create your own that.

Here is the snippet that I modified from the `cw` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>rl</Title>
            <Shortcut>rl</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for Console.ReadLine</Description>
            <Author>Xiaoy312</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>input</ID>
                    <ToolTip>variable for console input</ToolTip>
                    <Default>input</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal Editable="false">
                    <ID>SystemConsole</ID>
                    <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Console)</Function>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[var $input$ = $SystemConsole$.ReadLine();$end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Just drop it in your snippet folder. I put mine there :

> C:\Users\Xiaoy\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\CodeSnippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets\rl.snippet

When you type `rl` and <kbd>tab</kbd> twice, you get this :

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using VSCode, install the [C# Snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jorgeserrano.vscode-csharp-snippets) - it includes many snippets including Console.ReadLine().

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2022 (Mac), you can add a custom snippet as follows:

1. Click on `Visual Studio` in the toolbar
2. Click on `Preferences`, scroll down to Code Snippets
3. Click on `Add`
4. Enter your preferred shortcut, e.g. `crel`, C# as the
   `Group` and a Mime type, `text/x-chsarp`
5. In the large textarea below, enter the following (worked for me):
   `$SystemConsoleReadLine$ ($end$)`

Following this, `crel` + <kbd>tab</kbd> X2 should print out Syste.Console.ReadLine()